# finding homogeneous objects in a json object and keep them in array

Tags: c#, json, recursion

I have a Json Object as following:

```
{
'Aug':{
       'val1':132,
       'val2':'some text' 
},
'Jun':{
       'val1': 1231,
       'val2': 'other text'
    },
'description':'Description'
}
```

But i want to obtain result as following

```
{
'values':[
{
'key':'Aug',
'val1':132,
'val2':'some text'
},
{
'key':'Jun',
'val1':1231,
'val2':'other text'
}
],
'description':'Description'
}
```

I want to perform the conversion in c# using generic method. The keys and values provided are for reference only and varies.

Comment: I have tried recursive approach to pull data from each node until primitive data type is reached and added the 'key' key in interior json object , but not being able to group homogeneous object in array. I have thought of removing the un-necessary keys temporarily and then tried inserting again, but inserting seems to be tougher than i though.